# Unable to replace a string via regex through a subroutine

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, subroutine

I am trying to replace square brackets in a string with an empty string. which means if a string is `[SECTION]`, I want to convert it to `SECTION`.

I have tried this and it works,

```
my $sectionName =~ tr/[]//d;
print "$sectionName\n";
```

However, when I tried to create a general subroutine for replacing strings, it didn't work out. Here's what I tried,

```
sub strReplace
{
    my $string = shift;
    my $target = shift;     
    my $replacement = shift;

    $target = quotemeta $target;
    $replacement = quotemeta $replacement;

    $string =~ tr/$target/$replacement/d;

    return $string;
}
```

I am calling the sub like this,

```
# the string "[SECTION]" below is intended to be replaced by a variable
my $sectionName = strReplace("[SECTION]", "[]", "");
print "$sectionName\n";
```

However, instead of getting the replaced string, I am still getting the old one, i.e, `[SECTION]`. What am I doing wrong? (PS: Perl version 5.14.2)

Comment: It appears `tr` does not support variables:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382657/perls-tr-is-not-doing-what-i-want

Comment: BTW, I was confused by your subject line.  `tr` does not use regular expressions.  The first argument is a set of characters to look for (not a regex), and the second argument is what characters to replace those characters with, if any.  When I first set out to answer this question, I hadn't noticed the `tr` and though you were looking for the substring `"[]"` in `"[SECTION"`, which of course would not work.

Comment: Thanks, never knew `tr` doesn't support variables (and that it doesn't use regex), went along with `s///g` construct which works fine.

Comment: @ysth : Done!  I also summarized the two strategies at that link in the body of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl's `tr///` operator does not support variables.  You can find various strategies to work around this here:  [Perl's tr/// is not doing what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382657/perls-tr-is-not-doing-what-i-want)

To summarize, you have two main options:

- Wrap your `tr///` in an eval.
- Convert your `tr///` into a substitution using `s///`.

Answer (score 1):

If your main case for strReplace is actually just to remove characters, I'd write a less-general-purpose sub that does that.  Otherwise, a `s///` conversion that can both remove and replace looks like this:

```
sub strReplace
{
    my $string = shift;
    my $target = shift;
    my $replacement = shift;

    my %replacement;
    @replacement{ split //, $target } = split //, $replacement;

    $string =~ s{ ([\Q$target\E]) }{ $replacement{$1} // '' }gxe;

    return $string;
}
```

The substitution repeatedly (because of the /g flag) looks for `[\Q$target\E]` (a character in a class of any the characters in $target, any special characters automatically escaped if necessary by `\Q...\E`), and replaces it with the value found by looking in the hash, or just removes it if it wasn't found in the hash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you could you explain this syntax, specially the s/// construct you are using? I am not completely sure exactly how it works

Comment: Tried to explain, but it's hard without knowing what part(s) you weren't sure about.